# How to use explode after this because In My database column all values are available in product column like this

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode, implode

I am creating a database to store user information and products linked to the user. I store the products by imploding them with a `,`. How do I explode them later?

HTML Form:

```
<form name="frm" method="post">

<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" required ></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" required ></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" required></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="laptop">Laptop
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="pc">Pc
        <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="tablet">Tablet
    </td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

In Php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name=$_POST['txt'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $product=$_POST['chk'];

    foreach($product as $result)
    {
        $csk[]=$result;
    }
    //print_r($csk); exit;
    $rko=implode(",",$csk);

    $rec=mysql_query("insert into test(name,email,pass,product) values('".$name."','".$email."','".$pass."','".$rko."')");

    if($rec)
    {
        echo "Successfully Added";
    }
    else
    {
        echo " Failed To Add";
    }
}
```

The database will contain records like this:

```
+----+------+-------------+------+------------------+
| id | name | email       | pass | product          |
|  1 | kodi | k@gmail.com | kodi | laptop,pc        |
|  2 | muru | m@gmail.com | kodi | laptop,pc,tablet |
+----+------+-------------+------+------------------+
```

I want to know how to explode this and I want to know how to write a query to find people who have a laptop, pc, tablet or some combination.

Comment: It would be better to use a junction table instead of storing comma separated values in a column. It will save you many headaches in the future - and fix this problem too ...

Comment: ok what is junction table,then how to solve this type requirement .what I knew I  have implemented sir, kindly help me to solve this requirement sir.

Comment: kindly give me the idea stack team

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL wildcards to search in the product field:

```
SELECT * FROM `dbtable` WHERE `product` LIKE '%tablet%' OR `product` LIKE '%laptop%';
```

To separate the results, you would do:

```
$res = explode(",", $result['product']);
foreach ($res as $item) {
    echo "has $item ";
}
```

A better way to do it would be:

- You should consider not storing plain-text passwords.
- You should have joined tables that actually have a relationship between the person and the items. For example:

  Table `people`

  ```
  +----+------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | id | name | email       | password_hash                                                    |
  |  1 | kodi | k@gmail.com | 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824 |
  |  2 | muru | m@gmail.com | c0e81794384491161f1777c232bc6bd9ec38f616560b120fda8e90f383853542 |
  +----+------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
  ```

  Table `stuff`

  ```
  +----+-----------+--------+
  | id | person_id | item   |
  |  1 |         1 | laptop |
  |  2 |         1 | pc     |
  |  3 |         2 | laptop |
  |  4 |         2 | pc     |
  |  5 |         2 | tablet |
  +----+------+-------------+
  ```

  Then your query would be:

  ```
  SELECT p.* 
  FROM `people` AS `p` LEFT JOIN 
       `stuff` AS `s` ON `p`.`id` = `s`.`person_id` 
  WHERE `s`.item IN ('laptop','tablet');
  ```

Comment: Beat me to it – beautiful answer. Only thing I would add for the OP is that he is using the outdated `mysql` family of functions.

Comment: Thanks lot I have question here How do I pass the people id to stuff table person_id

Comment: before insert to table shall i want  to create another table stuff and insert the pi and item name correct me if i am wrong

Comment: i am waiting for that clarification

Comment: @user3804431 First, all these questions are answered by volunteers when they have time, so you need to be patient. Second, I do not understand what you are seeking clarification about. All you need to do is match the `person_id` in the `stuff` table to the `id` in the `person` or `people` table. You can do that manually or you can use an ORM (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/orm/info) to do it for you.

Comment: ok thanks lot I will study this and also by using mysql_insert_id function I will retrieve the last inserted data and I i will push to  stuff table this is my idea.once again thanks for stack team correct me if i am wrong